# How to make loop

Tags: php

This would helps me a lot to understand how does loop works

Let say i've database table `my_table (id,words)` and here is example of database

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1,'hello manal');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (2,'nice manal');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (3,'pretty manal');
```

now imagine for 100,000 entries (huge) and i want to replce the word manal to jack and giving me results every line changed one by one

i'll use

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','USER','PASS') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('my_table',$conn);

$sql = "SELECT * from my_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$old = $row['words'];
$id = $row['id'];

$new="jack";
$new = str_replace("manal", "$new", $old);
echo $new;

}
```

**The loop**
by that code it will works all at once which is impossible to my hosting server to apply all so i want to make it as loop ! i mean it will change the 1st database line then gives me the results `echo $new;` then change the 2nd database line then gives the results `echo $new;` and so on with no stop till last line.

so my important part is getting the results one by one ~thanks

Comment: So you want to update the database? Or just the output? Why not use MySQL 'UPDATE' ?

Comment: i want to print out the output of each line changes and this is just example so i can apply it later on delete/edit/update ..etc so i want just to print out the output line by line (i mean i want to apply changes on 1st line then gives results then apply changes on 2nd line and gives results and so on ..)

Comment: Isn't that what your code achieves? Line-by-line string replacement on each row in `my_table` and echoes its out to you (aka gives results)?

Comment: @josh yes it does but it does not print the output changes line by line , it shows all once ! someone did advices me to use "for {}" i really do not knows ! so any idea.

Comment: If you want to add breaks between each row, use `echo $new . "<br/>";` instead of `echo $new;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be that your output is being buffered which is why you see all the results at the same time (at the end of the execution of the script).

You could add `ob_flush(); flush();` within the loop before `echo $new;` an see if that helps. Regardless, the above example is going to execute pretty quickly so it isn't exactly going to be easily readable!

Answer (score 1):

You better do this replace in the database itself and then you just print it out.

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET words = REPLACE(words, 'manal', 'jack')";
```

Comment: I literally just asked why they aren't doing that in a comment. Unless they don't want to update the actual table

Comment: ~thanks but doesn't matter of update ways i just asking of how to apply changes on 1st line then gives result then apply changes on 2nd line and gives result and so on.